# Contact Merge Showing this error

Tags: opportunity, account, contact, campaign, merge

I was trying to merge two contacts which throw this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a custom validation message. So check all validation on Contact, related child.

You have to either deactivate this validation rule or need to fix the data first to pass this validation.